# RxJava + Retrofit Unit Test Kotlin Always Failed

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I tried to create Unit Test using Rxjava + Retrofit but it always give an error.

I have tried all tutorials and reference related of my questions. I did success when create an unit test of other method (other case), but failed in this case (Rx + retrofit).

Request Data Code:

```
fun getDetailEvent(idEvent: String?) {
        view.showLoading()
        apiService.getDetailEvent(idEvent)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe {
                    val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable? = null
                    compositeDisposable?.add(it)
                }
                .doFinally { view.hideLoading() }
                .subscribe({
                    val listModel = it
                    if (listModel != null) {
                        view.onDetailEventLoaded(listModel)
                    } else {
                        view.onDetailEventLoadFailed("Empty or Error List")
                    }
                },
                        {
                            val errorMessage = it.message
                            if (errorMessage != null) {
                                view.onDetailEventLoadFailed(errorMessage)
                            }
                        })
    }
```

Unit Test Code :

class DetailNextMatchPresenterTest {

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var view : DetailNextMatchView

    @Mock
    private lateinit var apiService: ApiService

    private lateinit var presenter: DetailNextMatchPresenter

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        presenter = DetailNextMatchPresenter(view, apiService)


    }

    @Test
    fun getDetailEvent() {
        val event : MutableList<EventModel> = mutableListOf()
        val response = ResponseEventModel(event)
        val idEvent = "44163"

        `when`(apiService.getDetailEvent(idEvent)
                .test()
                .assertSubscribed()
                .assertValue(response)
                .assertComplete()
                .assertNoErrors()
        )

        presenter.getDetailEvent(idEvent)

        verify(view).showLoading()
        verify(view).onDetailEventLoaded(response)
        verify(view).hideLoading()
    }
}
```

I appreciate all suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that you haven't forced your code to behave synchronously in the context of your test, so the Observable runs in parallel to your test. Try adding this in your setup method:

`RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }` If you're using RxJava2. Try looking for a similar method if you're using RxJava 1.